# load node.js nosql database, display sample data from it on total.js site

Tags: node.js, total.js, nosql

I am not very clear on how to use [node.js nosql](https://github.com/petersirka/nosql) with total.js (both are node.js modules).

- How do I set up the backend database?
- How do I programmatically create data **from a custom/unessential js script**, like a table that would serve for user accounts?
- Where do I load nosql with total.js (where, maybe `debug.js`, am I adding code/what is the code)?
- How can I display on a page view, for example, a *username* from that database (how do I access the data?)

No matter what your solution, please follow these instructions, or be sure to discuss any change:

1. `mkdir project_folder; cd project_folder`
2. `npm init`
3. `npm install --save nosql`
4. `npm install --save total.js`
5. unzip and install empty_project.zip from total.js's download area on github, but do not overwrite files *(npm has fresher files than are packaged and ready to go from github)*

Answer (score 1):

total.js contains **NoSQL embedded database** (you don't have to install NoSQL). Basically you can use (and look into the `/app/databases` directory):

```
framework.database('users').insert({ alias: 'Peter' });
```

Comment: thanks Mr. Sirka — to make sure: so even if I don't already have a "users" database, that will create the database for me .. and then later I can use I suppose a `framework.database('users').get({ alias: "Peter" }).first` or something to access the data for display?

Comment: Yes, yes but here is a full documentation: https://github.com/petersirka/nosql  ---> `F.database('users').` === `nosql.`. Thanks :-)

Comment: may I ask how should I do to code nosql in my app? I have code the simple web using totaljs. However, I confused where I should code nosql and how to configure the nosql code to my intire app code.